# Why does my form not submit when I disable the submit after the first click?

Tags: php, jquery, submit

I am trying to disable the submit button on a form so when the user clicks it twice it won't submit it again. I know there are already a few questions here that address that, but the solutions offered don't seem to be working.

I am using the solution offered here: [Disable submit button on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit)

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('form#proof_form').submit(function(){
    $(this).children('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

After the submit button is pushed it is supposed to enter a saved value to a DB and then redirect to another page. Instead it is now reloading the current page without redirecting. I placed a test echo right after the user pushes the submit button and it doesn't work. Also the value is no longer posting to the DB, so I know it is disabling the submit button before it can send to the DB and redirect.

Here is my php:

```
if(isset($_POST['accept_proof'])){
    echo 'The form was submitted!';
    $sql = 'INSERT into orders SET
          name = "' . $_SESSION['name'] . '"';
    $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
}
```

Why is the button not submitting after the first click?

Comment: Is form submitted without JS event on button submit ?

Comment: Does it actually work if you take that one disable line out and leave everything else alone?

Answer (score 2):

[Disabled HTML form elements are not submitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12).

I'm guessing 'accept_proof' is the name of your submit button, so, because it's being disabled before the form is submitted, its value is not set in the POST to the server; `isset($_POST['accept_proof'])` is returning false, and your code inside the `if` isn't executing.

You'll need to check for the POSTed form some other way, e.g. `isset()` on a different field in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "return false;"

Try this instead :

```
$('form#proof_form').submit(function(){
    $(this).children('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return false;
});
```

It works for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/5S72w/2/

Comment: Returning false from the submit event stops the form from being submitted at all. The button will disable correctly, but the page will just sit there. (This problem is a server-side one, so can't really be demonstrated on jsFiddle.)

Answer (score 0):

If the same page is refreshing, i think you forgot to put your `form`'s `action` attribute.
You should have this:

```
<form action="your_action" ...> 
  ... 
</form>
```

HOpe this helps. Cheers

Comment: He is redirecting to another page.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on this all day. My version of the submit button calls a validate function `onclick`, and then disables the button at the end of the validation. The problem I had was that since the button is disabled, and the form's action is not what I need, the button does not submit the form once it is disabled.

After hours of searching around the internet, I found that all I had to do was to call my form's `submit()` function after the disabling to submit the form.

So if my form's name is `myform`

then I call `myform.submit()` after the disabling.

Hope this helps