# PHP statement to display image if sql record is new

Tags: php, mysql

could someone help me, i need a php statement that will display an image if an sql record is created within the last week.

My website has a profile page setup and im look to display a new icon on all the latest records

i have a date stamp field on my database called date

can anyone assist

Thanks

Comment: Define "date stamp field". What type is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is basically the same as [Check if mySQL record added in the last x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400779/check-if-mysql-record-added-in-the-last-x-seconds/6400822#6400822)

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE `date` > (now() - interval 7 DAY)";
$result=mysql_query($stmt);
foreach($result as $rec){
    echo "<img src=\"yourimage.jpg\" />";
    //do some more stuff with the mysql result if required
}
```

Comment: im not looking to query the database, i have a query that outputs what i require. I need a PHP statement that says something like if created within 7 days display image?

Comment: added a php example (which assumes you have a existing mysql connection, eg, mysql_connect(.....) mysql_select_db(....) .....
this will display an image for EACH record created within the last 7 days, not sure if that is what you want

Comment: @Craig Nicholls: if you're `not looking to query the database` why the  you even mentioned mysql in your question? Remove everything about db in your question, so we know what you actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( (strtotime($row['date'])+7*86400)>time() )
  echo "<img src=\"new.jpg\" alt=\"new\" />";
```