# Ajax disabled button after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable submit button on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit)

I have a question about disable button after ajax submit.
Actually the button disabled first until I input text to textarea. Then if I submit with click button, it must disable the button.

In my actual, after click button, the button isn't disabled.

Here it's my JS code :

```
$(function()
    {
        $("#submit_h").click(function() 
        {
            var haps = $("#haps").val();
            var dataString = 'haps='+ haps;
            if(haps=='')
            {
                alert('Please type your haps');
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "post_haps.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                $("#haps").val('');
                $("#content").prepend(html);
                }
                });
            }return false;
        });
    });
```

--

```
<textarea id="haps"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="button inact" value="Share" disabled="disabled" id="submit_h"/>
```

Now what I want to do is, disabled the button after submit.
Any idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to NullUserException's link, you can use jquery to set the "disabled" attribute:

```
$(".inact").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: I mean disabled after submit, not on submit. So if after submit the button must be disabled until I fill text to texarea.

Comment: From a user experience, is there a difference between it being disabled "on submit" vs "after submit"?  How long after they submit are you wanting to wait?  Simply use the code I provided at a location in your code that corresponds with your timing needs.

Comment: Thanks for your explain, now I got the login. :)

Answer (score 1):

Disable the button in ajax success:

```
success: function(html){
                $("#haps").val('');
                $("#content").prepend(html);
                $("#submit_h").attr("disabled", true);
                       }
```