# Disable submit button on click after form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form, which has a jquery form validation.. what i need is the submit button should get disabled when i submit the form once the validation is done..

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
    Location: <input name="location" type="text" />
    Site: <input name="site" type="text" />
    Age: <input name="age" type="text" />
    Gender <input name="gender" type="text" />
    <input name="button" type="submit" class="myButton" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

here is my form [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgYpX/)

Comment: when you submit a form the page reloads...so i am wondering why do  you need to disable the button....anyways  either use ajax to post the form or save the button flag in cookie or db and check that

Comment: I haven't tried, because i am not very good in javascript.. Sorry

Comment: This form data is storing in a database its taking 2-3 seconds, in the meantime user is clicking submit button again and again.. due to this i am getting duplicate entries.

Comment: @Ajeesh you need to redirect the user away from the posted values page! header('/same_page.php');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you want to disable the submit button but using jQuery you could do

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
```

Typically you either wouldnt have a submit button, or else submit the form and the page will reload!

**UPDATE**

To stop people from reposting the values by refreshing the page as you wrote in comments, redirect the user to the page without the values posted!

```
 header('/same_page.php');
```

Comment: is that `prop("disabled",true)` ?

Answer (score 4):

you want to do the action on form.submit. Not sure if you need to add form.valid() there as a check, but I always do it like that. Afterwards you can return true or false.

- True: The browser proceeds with the link and action specified in the form
- False: The browser stops (when you have validation errors)

Here the code:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    if (!$('#myform').valid()) return false;

    $('#myform input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return true;
});
```

I've also updated your fiddle with that code, so you can try it out

Answer (score 2):

after you validate the form, use:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function(event) {
        if($('#myform').valid()) {
            $(event.target).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable once the form which you want to validate is valid, then you can disable the submit button like this

```
$("#myForm").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other stuff for a valid form
    $('#myform input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    form.submit();
  }
});
```