# How to disable a submit button in javascript after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a button tag to create the button. I want to disable the button when I click on it. But I'm not able to do it. I hope someone here can help me...

Comment: give some code what you have tried!

Comment: also, why do not you try with input tag giving type = 'Button'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable submit button ONLY after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106885/disable-submit-button-only-after-submit)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you be more specific about your problem, please? If possible, please add your HTML and your JavaScript, if you have tried some, but at least your HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `.disabled` property of the button.

```
var btn = document.querySelector("#submit-btn");
btn.disabled = true;
```

**Live example:**

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("#submit-btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  submit();
});
function submit() {
  btn.disabled = true;
}
```

```css
#submit-btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid black .5px;
}
#submit-btn:disabled {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Submit">
```

Resourced from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button).

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<input type="button" id="btn1" onClick="clicked()" value="text">`

JS

```
function clicked(){
    var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
    btn1.disabled = true;
}
```