# I would like to make the submit button disable just after submitting

Tags: javascript, html, submit, addeventlistener

I would like to make the SUBMIT-BUTTON disable just after submitting.
Here is what I wrote and it doesn't work. Could you please give me a clue what the problem is?

```
<div>
    <form id="manual_form" action="" method="POST">
        <button id="button" type="submit" name="manual_start">SUBMIT！</button>
    </form>
</div>
<hr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let manual_form = document.getElementById('manual_form');
    let manual_button = document.getElementById('button');

    manual_form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
        console.log('submitted!');
        manual_button.disabled = true;
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the `submit` button, the page reloads. That is why you don't see the `disabled` attribute in action. You can add `evt.preventDefault();` in the event Handler to prevent the reloading

```js
let manual_form = document.getElementById('manual_form');
let manual_button = document.getElementById('button');

manual_form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitted!');
  manual_button.disabled = true;
}, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="manual_form" action="" method="POST">
    <button id="button" type="submit" name="manual_start">SUBMIT！</button>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now I understand why it didn't work. But my wish is to post the data first and then make the button disable. If the page isn't reloaded, the data will not be sent, will it? Should I use xmlHttpRequest or this kind?

Comment: Yes. For this kind of work, you can use xmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The `submit` can be disabled using the `setAttribute()` method by assigning the appropriate `disabled` attribute. In your case, it will be like this:

```
...
manual_button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
...
```

```js
let manual_form = document.getElementById('manual_form');
    let manual_button = document.getElementById('button');

    manual_form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log('submitted!');
        manual_button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }, false);
```

```html
<div>
    <form id="manual_form" action="" method="POST">
        <button id="button" type="submit" name="manual_start">SUBMIT！</button>
    </form>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey for your answer! Now I understand why it didn't work. But my wish is to post the data first and then make the button disable. If the page isn't reloaded, the data will not be sent.

Comment: To do this, you need to remove the `evt.preventDefault()` line. And your button will work as expected. I was glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript side works it's something about the form... when the page is refreshed it throws an error.
Add `evt.preventDefault();` inside the event listener function to stop the page from refreshing. The button is disabled.