# Disable button on click but still process form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to disable my register button on click to prevent spam, but I don't want to prevent the form the button submits from submitting.

I'm able to disable the button on click, but can't figure out why the form still won't submit...

button:

```
<?= form_open("course/registerCourse", "method='post'") ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="session" value="<?= $session["id"] ?>">
   <button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn btn-success register">REGISTER</button>
<?= form_close() ?>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.register').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    $("form").submit();
});
```

register function:

```
public function registerCourse()
{

    $user = $this->users_model->userAccountTP();
    $appParticipant = $user[0]["id"];

    $author_id = $this->session->userdata("ci_user_id");
    $appSession = $this->input->post('session');

    $this->ci_channel_entry_model->save_multiple(array(
        "channel_id" => 11,
        "title" => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
        "author_id" => $author_id,
        "status_id" => 7,
        "date" => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
        "data" => array(
            array(
                // application-session
                "field_id" => 28,
                "content" => $appSession
            ),
            array(
                // application-participant
                "field_id" => 29,
                "content" => $appParticipant
            )
        ),
        "hook" => FALSE
    ));

    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting $("form").submit(); before adding the disabled attribute to the button?

Comment: what'd be the point of this? your form doesn't have to get filled out. a spammer can just directly submit your field=value pairs directly to the server with out EVER loading your form.

Comment: Tried that and still isn't working

Comment: @MarcB if a user presses the register button multiple times while the form is submitting, multiple registration requests are posted the server. Disabling the button would allow the form to submit with only one request.

Comment: can you show exactly your form code?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I've added the function the form posts to my question. The form itself isn't more than what I'd already shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up reworking my form to align with this answer and everything worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5691065/4141833

Answer (score 4):

I think you might have a typo, because I dont see where you are declaring `$form`, so maybe this helps:

```
$('.register').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I made that fix but I'm still having issues.