# Django prevent page caching

Tags: django

**strong text**I am trying to prevent a page being cached as I dont want the user to be able to resubmit a form which has already been saved to the db.

I tried the following in views.py

```
class ServiceCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Service
    form_class = ServiceCreateForm

    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ServiceCreate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, this has no effect as the entire page is shown instantly when the user hits the back button. How can I prevent caching please?

**Update**
I'm new to Django so thought that the decorator would instruct the browser not to cache - I did not appreciate that there was server caching as well.

Comment: That sounds like browser caching is the issue...

Comment: Search for PRG pattern. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing has nothing to do with server caching- it is all browser side.

Ultimately you can't 100% guarantee that a form won't be submitted multiple times (users *will* find a way...), so you'll have to handle that gracefully on the server. However you can greatly reduce the likelihood of it:

- Return an [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) (or use the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut) to redirect the browser after a successful form submission. This will prevent a browser refresh from resubmitting the form.
- Use [javascript to disable the form submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5691065) after the form as been submitted. I recently had some weird errors and data inconsistencies that turned out to be caused by someone double clicking a form's submit button. Disabling the button after the first click resolved the issue (along with doing more validation server-side to recognize a duplicate submission).
- Make sure that you use `POST` (rather than `GET`) to submit the form. Browsers are less likely to resubmit the form casually and I believe that [Django's CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) *should* also help prevent errant submissions.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I think your second suggestion of disabling the submit button will be the best.