# How to disable summit button after only one click , and it should be not disabled if there are validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a submit button, i need this button to be disabled after only one click , and it should be not disabled if there are validation errors. i am using the following,

```
onclick="var e = this; setTimeout(function () { e.disabled = true; e.value='Please wait...'}, 0); return true;"
```

but this makes the button remain disabled if there are validation errors which i don't want.

here is the submit button code

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="var e = this; setTimeout(function () { e.disabled = true; e.value='Please wait...'}, 0); return true;" value="Confirm Selected" />
```

How do i achieve this using `jquery` or `JavaScript` ?

Note: I have looked into stack overflow questions, but the answers don't handle when there is a validation errors.

[this does not work after validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit)

Comment: What type validation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `html validations` like `input tag` with `type email` you should use 
`form submit` instead of `button click` because form only submits when there is no error in the form. for form submitting you can try as below:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the validation you are using and the way everything is set.

It might work for you if, instead of a timeout, you try with setInterval();

You can have a flag that is set to "disable" on button click you can also initiate the interval which will check for errors every N seconds. If there are no errors it will call a function that changes the submit button to the initial/new state, change the "disable" flag, and clear the interval.