# js this.form.submit(); ignore the required input html

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

i got this registeration for user,i use the js function at the submit button to prevent user from double click,but now the form will submit even though user did not inside name which is required,what should i do

```
<?php echo form_open('user/register_cust_checkout',array('class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'')) ?>

    <div class="row col-12 pr-0">
      <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Nama Penuh</label>
          <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control uppercase" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6  pr-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">No K / P</label>
          <input type="text" name="nic_no" class="form-control uppercase">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-12 pr-0">
      <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Emel</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6  pr-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">No Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Alamat</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="example-textarea" name="address" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-12 pr-0">
      <div class="col-md-6  pr-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Poskod</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control uppercase">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Bandar</label>
            <input type="text" name="town_area" class="form-control uppercase">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="custom-select">Negeri</label>
        <select class="custom-select select2" name="state_id" id="custom-select">
          <option value="17" selected>---Pilih---</option>
          <option value="1">SELANGOR</option>
          <option value="2">KUALA LUMPUR</option>
          <option value="3">JOHOR</option>
          <option value="4">PERAK</option>
          <option value="5">PENANG</option>
          <option value="6">KEDAH</option>
          <option value="7">PAHANG</option>
          <option value="8">NEGERI SEMBILAM</option>
          <option value="9">KELANTAN</option>
          <option value="10">TERENGGANU</option>
          <option value="11">MELAKA</option>
          <option value="12">PUTRAJAYA</option>
          <option value="13">PERLIS</option>
          <option value="14">LABUAN</option>
          <option value="15">SABAH</option>
          <option value="16">SARAWAK</option>
        </select>
      </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
      <input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sila 
       Tunggu';this.form.submit();" id="btn_upd" class="btn btn-primary" value="Daftar">
    </div>

    <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

javascript code (onclick) :

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sila 
   Tunggu';this.form.submit();" id="btn_upd" class="btn btn-primary" value="Daftar">
```

so this is my register form,user can even register even though the form is blank because this.form.submit(); ignore the required input form

Comment: Where's the javascript code? Hard to help without a [mre] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: i update the  javascript code

Comment: The html5 validation is being bypassed when you dd `this.form.submit()` in the button `onclick`. The default action of the click is to submit the form and activate the validation. Bypassing with js doesn't make sense

Comment: so what should i do if i need the required validation and prevent user from double click submit button

Comment: How about [disabling the submit button after it has been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691054/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit/5691065)?

Comment: ok i will try that