# How to disable not dblclick.. but double click submitting.. form and link submissions

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form id="login" method='post' action='membership.php'>
    <b>Email</b><br><br>
    <input class="form" type='text' name='email2' id='email2'><br><br>
    <b>Password</b><br><br>
    <input class="form" type='password' name='password2' id='password2'><br><br>
    <input class="submitborder" id='submit2' type='submit' name='submit2' value='Submit'>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit2").on("click", function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        Submitting();
    });
});

function Submitting() {
    setTimeout('$("#submit2").removeAttr("disabled")', 10000);
}

function PreventDouble(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>

<?php
echo "<a href='construction.php' onclick='PreventDouble(this)'></a>";
?>
```

I've read a few forum pages etc ... and they suggest disabling using jQuery or AJAX. When I disable though, I doesn't submit the form data anymore. But will disable the button accordingly.

For the hyperlink, because it sends user to another page, then disables, it's hard to judge if `onclick='PreventDouble(this);'` is working.

I also would like to apologize as I am a newb when it comes to Javascript, jQuery, or AJAX.

**UPDATE:** May I also mention I'm newb at this forum posting. Um. One last note is the disabling of form button.  I use this code in another area of my website that doesn't click properly on computer. As if it seems to be on a wait before it processes my Javascript/jQuery/AJAX scripts? I dunno.

I admit defeat to Javascript/jQuery/AJAX x_x

Comment: Your form fields do not match your Javascript / jQuery selectors. Fix your code.

Comment: I think you are trying to prevent the form being submitted twice, eg by clicking the button 2 times quickly? The code you have shown will do that - it disables the button, but does not stop the form submission.  Depending on how long the network request to submit your form takes, your `Submitting()` may or may not actually run.  There is no need for it though - when your form POST actually happens, the browser will leave this form page and the button disappears anyway.  Re-enabling it just before that happens only allows another click, if someone is determined.

Comment: No the second I incorporate either that code or this code onclick='this.disabled=true'  it disables form submission. So then im left having to submit the form using javascript instead php? if that makes sense @_@

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery disable submit button on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445431/jquery-disable-submit-button-on-form-submission)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong as I am not familiar with PHP, but it doesn't look like the `PreventDouble(this)` method get called upon form submission. You can try putting the function inside the click event handler instead. Or better yet, just put the `event.preventDefault()` line there.

Comment: im trying to prevent over clicking of forms, links, and buttons. In the php code it echo's(prints) html code that has javascript function PreventDouble() in it.. The question I wonder is if this code is right.. For the javascript function in reference to hyperlinks. It has nothing to do with the form submission. I have two different questions here. @_@ But I will try this.. "click event handler"